# SAS proc SQL iteration

Tags: sas

Below is the initial macro code

```
%let bdate='01JAN2001'd ;
%let bno=11;
%let date='01JAN2001'd ;
%let sno=%eval(&bno + %sysfunc(intck(month,&bdate,&date)));
%let no=%eval(&sno.+2)
%put &=date &=sno &=no;
DATE='01JAN2001'd SNO=11 no=13
```

I want to two things to do. Put the values from sno to no into new dataset like 
 below.

```
no 
11
12
13
```

Second I want to iterate below proc SQL based on above resolved macro sno to no, I mean as per above values it has to be loop from 11,12 and 13 without using macros.

```
proc sql;
create table new &no as select from sample where deal in (&no);
quit;
```

So below is the iterated proc SQL logic after using above resolved macros.

```
proc SQL;
create table new11 as select from sample where deal in (11);
quit;

proc SQL;
create table new12 as select from sample where deal in (12);
quit;

proc SQL;
create table new13 as select from sample where deal in (13);
quit;
```

I dont want to put above proc SQL into macro and mend process. It has to continue from.

```
%put &=date &=sno &=no;
```

Comment: You want macro like functionality without macros? Have you looked at DOSUBL or CALL EXECUTE? Likely CALL EXECUTE. It's not usually a good idea to split your data like that...you're likely going to go down a road of all macros now rather than BY or GROUP processing.

Answer (score 0):

The way to loop like this without a macro is using `call execute`. However, in most cases using a macro will result in code that is easier to write and understand. If you have to stay away from macros for some reason, you could accomplish what you are describing like this:

```
%let bdate='01JAN2001'd ;
%let bno=11;
%let date='01JAN2001'd ;
%let sno=%eval(&bno + %sysfunc(intck(month,&bdate,&date)));
%let no=%eval(&sno + 2);
%put &date &sno &no;

data sno_to_no;
    do no = &sno to &no;
        output;
    end;
run;

data sample;
    set sno_to_no;
    deal = no;
run;

data _null_;
    set sno_to_no;
    call execute('proc sql; create table new'||strip(no)||' as select * from sample where deal in ('||strip(no)||'); quit;');
run;
```

You may be able to simplify by just putting the call execute right before the `output` statement in the `sno_to_no` data step, depending on your needs. You obviously won't need the `sample` data step I provided here - I included it so the code would run for my example.